# PHP + Xdebug + PHP Strom: Как дебажить MVC-приложение, если xdebug соскакивает на роутере, не идет дальше..?

Tags: phpstorm, отладка, xdebug, отладчик, remote-debugging

xdebug у меня в PHP Storm установлен через файл, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пытаюсь посмотреть, что приходит в контроллер, то это не выходит. Из индексного файла по точкам останова прохожу в router.php, но на коде:

```
public function processRequest()
    {
        $path = $this->findControllerAndMethod();
        $method = $path['method'];

        if(empty($path['argument'])) {
            (new $path['controller']())
                ->$method();
        } else {
            (new $path['controller']())
                ->$method($path['argument']);
        }
    }
```

у меня ставится Variables are not avilable.

Может это потому что работает приложение только через бразуер, там же нужен url для 'REQUEST_METHOD (где маршрутизация)...

Подскажите, пожалуйста что я делаю не так, как мне дебажить контроллеры?

Comment: Что значит "соскакивает"? Зачем такой долгий путь чтобы войти в метод? Вывод ошибок настроен в приложении? Никакие не выдаёт?  Почему не поставить точку останова прямо на первой строке контроллера? Причём тут REQUEST_METHOD  и что с ним не так? "телефончик" в phpstrom на панели дебага включен? ...............  "*как мне дебажить контроллеры?*" --- поставить бряк в метод контроллера и всё............. "*Variables are not avilable*" --- о каких variables речь? и где это показывает?

Comment: 1. соскакивает - доходит до точки останова напротив ->$method(); и дальше дебаггин прекращается,  консоли дебага уже нет никаких логово что пришло - что ушло только надпись Variables are not avilable.

Comment: 2. "Зачем такой долгий путь чтобы войти в метод?" - почему долго, вроде норм? ничего лишнего.. 3. в целом дебаг работает сам роутер он проходит и показывает в консоли дебага все данные, которые из переменной в переменную идут

Comment: 4. Попробовал в первую строчку контроллера поставить точку останова - все равно не работает

Comment: у меня без телефончика работает, но я его включил - не помогло, правда дебаг показывает $path = null и все другие в переменной null

Comment: Path он не получает, потому что вот так роутинг работает: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
            switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
                case ("/"):
                    return ['controller' => 'Controller\JsonApiReplyController', 'method' => 'getWholeCatalogue']

Comment: получается, если я дебажу, то, что из браузера информацию получает, мне обязательно в браузере расширение xdebug надо иметь?

Comment: нет, расширения никакие не нужны.......а вот телефончик нужно нажимать, это прослушка запроса...... сейчас видимо в phpstorm стоит в настройках что-то типа "break on first line" или break if not mapped в любом случае...

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант, что установлено расширение opcache и оно как-то излишне оптимизирует работу. В итоге временно можно его выключить в настройках php.ini

```
opcache.enable=0
```

и перезапустить сервер

Перезагрузить *PHPStrom* тоже не помешает

Comment: у меня nginx стоит на локальном сервере..

Comment: ............и что?

Comment: извините, слепой, у вас opcache, а читаю апач

Comment: посмотрел: у меня в ini такая настройка: opcache.enable => On => On

Comment: вот надо выключить.

Comment: попробую, что-то не найду как с моей инфраструктурой, может занять какое-то время..